# getting the only selected checkbox values in other page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart

I am modifying opencart for an resort booking company. For that i need to have multiple checkbox options in product page. But i am not getting from where is it calculating the unit price which includes all my checkbox, radio button selected options (price). If i want to edit it, where i can do it.

i will be having seasonwise date and values, when a checkbox selected it should compare the date selected by the user, if matches then get the value from there. Now i have added the start date and end date in `product_option_value` table. Through admin area we can enter the date infront of the perticular option.

I am not getting how and where only selected values get calculated in product/cart page.

Please suggest me

Here is my site, as i cannot attach images i am giving the link to see my page.

[resort](http://netelity.com/resort)

i will be having multiple selections in my product page, i mean three options for single, 3 options for adult ... (depending on the seasong) which am going to specify in date area of option tab in product page , through admin area. Now all my calculations are okay. But when i select the checkbox (say i select single), it should check the start date and end date with the user entered date, which 'single' (as there are multiple entries for single) has the date between the user entered date, it should pick the price for that, then it should give the unit price in cart page.

But now its just picking price without checking the date. If i can pass the ids of selected checkboxes without its price, then i can calculate the rest there. I am not getting this.

here is my catalog/controller/checkout/cart.php

```
$option_data[] = array(
                        'product_option_id' => $option['product_option_id'],
                        'option_id'         => $option['option_id'],
                        'type'              => $option['type'],
                        'name'              => $option['name'],
                        'price'             => $option['value'],
                        'value'             => (utf8_strlen($value) > 20 ? utf8_substr($value, 0, 20) . '..' : $value)
                    );
                    //echo $option['value'];
                    //echo $option['option_value_id'];

                    //echo $option['type'];

                    if($option['type'] == "checkbox")
                                {
                                    $id = $option['option_value_id'];
                                    //echo $id;
                                    }

                    if($option['name'] =="Check-In")
                    {
                        $this->data['value1'] = $value;
                        $this->data['date1'] = $this->data['value1'];
                        // $this->data['date1'];
                        $_SESSION['data12'] = $this->data['date1'];
                    }

                    //echo $_SESSION['data12'];
                    $this->data['mydate1'] = strtotime($_SESSION['data12']);

                    if($option['name'] == "Check-Out")
                    {
                    $this->data['value2'] = $option['option_value'];
                    $this->data['date2'] = $this->data['value2'];
                    $_SESSION['data13'] = $this->data['date2'];
                    // $this->data['date2'];
                    }
                $this->data['mydate2'] = strtotime($_SESSION['data13']);


                $difference = abs(($this->data['mydate2']) - ($this->data['mydate1']));
                $this->data['totaldays1'] = floor($difference/(60*60*24));

                // $this->data['totaldays1'];
                $total123 = (int)$this->data['totaldays1'];
                // $total123;
                $_SESSION['tot123'] = $total123;
                //$my3 = $_SESSION['tot123'];
                //$this->data['my3'] = $_SESSION['tot123'];
                }
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////MY CODE SHOULD GO HERE******************************************
                $roomRate = $this->currency->format($this->tax->getRatesofRooms($id, $_SESSION['data12'],$_SESSION['data13'] ));

                //$roomRate = $this->currency->format($this->tax->getRatesofRooms($id, $_SESSION['data12'],$_SESSION['data13'] ));

                //echo $roomRate;
                //$price = $roomRate;
                //echo $price;
                //$product['price'] = $roomRate;
                $product['price'] += $roomRate;
                //echo $product['price'];
                // Display prices
                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    //echo $price;
                } 

                else {
                    $price = false;
                }

                //$product['price'];
                // Display prices
                if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $total = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')) * $_SESSION['tot123']);
                } else {
                    $total = false;
                }

                // $total1;
                // $total1;

                $this->data['products'][] = array(
                    'key'      => $product['key'],
                    'thumb'    => $image,
                    'name'     => $product['name'],
                    'model'    => $product['model'],
                    //'checkin'  => $product['checkin'],
                    //'checkout'  => $product['checkout'],

                    'option'   => $option_data,
                    'quantity' => $product['quantity'],
                    'stock'    => $product['stock'] ? true : !(!$this->config->get('config_stock_checkout') || $this->config->get('config_stock_warning')),
                    'reward'   => ($product['reward'] ? sprintf($this->language->get('text_points'), $product['reward']) : ''),
                    'price'    => $price,
                    'total'    => $total,
                    'href'     => $this->url->link('product/product', 'product_id=' . $product['product_id']),
                    'remove'   => $this->url->link('checkout/cart', 'remove=' . $product['key'])
                );
            }
```

Here its calculating the price, which includes selected checkboxes price without comparing the date

```
if (($this->config->get('config_customer_price') && $this->customer->isLogged()) || !$this->config->get('config_customer_price')) {
                    $price = $this->currency->format($this->tax->calculate($product['price'], $product['tax_class_id'], $this->config->get('config_tax')));
                    //echo $price;
                } 

                else {
                    $price = false;
                }
```

i am not getting from where its getting selected checkboxes value. (demo/demo)
you can check the admin in this link by giving demo/demo
[http://netelity.com/resort/admin](http://netelity.com/admin)

Comment: can you post some of your codes? Its really hard to imagine! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the way I do. This might be little helpful for you:

**First, Make checkbox:**

```
<?php 
$i = 1;
foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
 <tr>
<td>   <input id="cb<?=$i; ?>" name="cb<?=$i; ?>" type="checkbox" onClick="check(<?=$i; ?>,<?=$res['entry_id']; ?> ,this.checked);" 
value="<?php echo $res['entry_id']; ?>" > </td>
 <td> //rest of your code </td>
 </tr>
<?php $i++; } ?>
```

**Make Javascript function:**

```
<script>
function check(cb_id,entry_id,val)
  {
     if(val == true){
         document.getElementById('cb_hidden_entry_id'+cb_id).value = entry_id;  
         //alert(document.getElementById('cb_hidden_entry_id'+cb_id).value);
     } else {
          document.getElementById('cb_hidden'+cb_id).value = '';
    }
  }
</script>
```

**And do this in your form:**

```
<form name="form_name" id="form_name" action="anotherpage.php" method="post">



        <?php 
        $i = 1;
        foreach ($result as $res) { ?>
            <input type="hidden" id="cb_hidden_entry_id<?=$i; ?>" name="cb_hidden_entry_id<?=$i; ?>" value="" >  
            <?php //rest of your code ?>
        <?php $i++; }  //foreach closed ?> 
      <input class="button" type="submit" name="btn_submit" id="btn_submit" value="Send Email"/></div>   


</form>
```

**And in your anotherpage.php file:**

```
<?php

$_POST = array_filter($_POST); //filter empty array in $_POST

echo '<pre>';
print_r($_POST);
?>
```

And, you will see the result.

Comment: thanks. But my problem is something different. I have edited my code please have a look.

Comment: Can somebody help me?

Comment: Hey i tried and it did work. Thanks . I made few modifications according to my table and it worked!

Comment: wow.. it's nice to hear from you. Thank you.. :)